# Blurred list view data browser when scrolling long list (OS X / Carbon)

Tags: macos, user-interface, macos-carbon

I have a carbon application with a list view data browser and vertical scrolling.  When the list is long (hundreds of items), rapid scrolling through the window produces blurred, sometimes "smeared" text:

[image: Screen shot of ListView]

Other artifacts can also occur, such as clipped or overlapping lines.  Sometimes the entire contents are nothing but a vortex-like smear.  Clicking any item causes a normal repaint of the ListView contents.  Here is how Interface Builder sees the ListView:

[image]

I am building against MacOSX10.5.sdk using Xcode 3.2.6.  Building and testing is under 10.6.  I am not doing any special handling of scroll events.  I have only defined `DataBrowserCallbacks` for `itemDataCallback`, `itemNotificationCallback`, and `itemCompareCallback`.

My question is: what could possibly cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, so here is the answer for posterity:

It turns out that the problem always and only occurs when the list view data browser is positioned at a non-integer horizontal offset.

`HIViewSetFrame()` takes an `HIRect` argument which uses `float` types for `origin` and `size`.  When the parent frame is resized such that the origin of the browser falls on a non-integer `origin.x`, the graphics errors are triggered.  It does not matter whether or not the vertical offset or either size dimension is non-integral.

The solution is to ensure that browsers which are moved when the window resizes have their x value rounded off:

```
frame.origin.x = roundf(frame.origin.x);
```

It does not appear that any other controls have any problems with non-integer origins.